# How can I deal with the webserver UI of one machine being out of sync with backend/API of another?

Tags: sql, datetime, webserver, ntp

The system my company sells is software for a multi-machine solution. In some cases, there is a UI on one of the machines and a backend/API on another. These systems communicate and both use their own clocks for various operations and storage values.

When the UI's system clock gets ahead of the backend by 30 seconds or more, the queries start to misbehave due to the UI's timestamp being sent over as key information to the REST request. There is a "what has been updated by me" query that happens every 30 seconds and the desync will cause the updated data to be missed since they are outside the timing window.

Since I do not have any control over the systems that my software is installed on, I need a solution on my code's side. I can't force customers to keep their clocks in sync.

Possible solutions I have considered:

- The UI can query the backend for it's system time and cache that.
- The backend/API can reach back further in time when looking for updates. This will give the clocks some room to slip around, but will cause a much heavier query load on systems with large sets of data.

Any ideas?

Comment: ....without having spent much time in this area, you should probably be caching server time on login (or equivalent), but my bigger question is, "why every 30 seconds?".  If you're doing something like autosaves, it should be "30 seconds, or the first time there was a change, whichever comes last".  Generally speaking, though, you should attempt to make the UI clock irrelevant (part of "don't trust the client" - what happens if a _future_ timestamp is given?).  Otherwise, I think we need more details on how this system interacts.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - I am very new in this area, but the changes that are done by the client are events like "change the owner of this entry" or maybe "change the status". No auto-saving at all. The web ui is designed to be used by 1-50 people simultaneously which is why the 30 second updates are important. But 30 seconds isn't really going to protect against race conditions... It is more of a "let's try our best to stay in sync" approach in its current state.

Comment: Actually the more I look around and the more I talk to people, it seems like having a network of machines properly configured with an NTP server is expected by any sysadmin. I think my worry on this topic is a little exaggerated. I am going to leave the question up for a day or two to see what people have to say, and then I will close it.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to restructure your API somewhat.

First, even though NTP is a good idea, you can't actually guarantee it's in use.  Additionally, even when it is enabled, OSs (Windows at least) may reject packets that are too far out of sync, to prevent certain attacks (on the order of minutes, though).

When dealing with distributed services like this, the mantra is "do not trust the client".  This applies even when you actually control the client, too, and doesn't necessarily mean the client is attempting anything malicious - it just means that the client isn't the authoritative source.
This should include timestamps.
Consider; the timestamps are a problem here because you're trying to use the client's time to query the server - except, we shouldn't trust the client.  Instead, what we should do is have the server return a timestamp of when the request was processed, or the update stamp for the latest entry of the database, that can be used in subsequent queries to retrieve new updates (how far back you go on initial query is up to you).

Dealing with concurrent updates safely is a little harder, and depends on what is supposed to happen on collision.  There's nothing really different here from most of the questions and answers dealing with database-centric versions of the problem, I'm just mentioning it to note you may need to add extra fields to your API to correctly handle or detect the situation, if you haven't already.

Comment: I like the approach of having the API tell the caller when the request was processed. This integrates the time sync into a call that is already being made. I can just cache the time of request processing and use that (and update it) for each subsequent request. Will report back after I work with this.